# DTMF digits ignoring by option?

Tags: asterisk, voip, pbx

The problem is when i call from my the mobile phone to my asterisk form extern line and try to choose internal number like example number 1 = 101 or 2 to call = 102 then get log like this below

my version of asterisk 11. + lcr + mIsdn

**[call=1122 ast=lcr/1] Recognised DTMF digit '2' by LCR, but ignoring.
(disabled by option)**

What option i have to enable? or maybe its wrong dialplan or 
can be problem with Dtmf options, for now i set for INFO still not sure. 
i never found any similar error .

Answer (score 0):

This means that you are receiving in-band dtmf but the detection for this is disabled (dsp_dtmf).

Most probably you have disabled DTMF in extensions.conf.

Check if the option is not accidentally set to “n” (and remove it or change the setting).